# Change install location if old installation used default location (Program Files/)

Tags: inno-setup

Old version of app was installed in /program files/xxx/ (1) or custom location

when installing the new version need to check if old version installed in default location (1)

if so

create /program files/yyy/ (2) and copy the files from old location and continue installation with location (2)

if old version installed in different location continue installation without changing location

any suggestions are welcomed

- how can I check from Inno Script if Old location exist
- how can I create a copy of the old location folder and rename it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm) and look under "File System functions" and "File functions".

You should use the `DirExists`, `FileCopy` and `RenameFile` functions for your purposes.