# Inno Setup ... Use old DB if previous version installed

Tags: inno-setup

I have an app written in VB6 with a MDB database.

When installing the latest version if user has an older version than I would like to copy the old DB Folder(Program Files/AppName/DATA/) to the new installation instead of setting up the default DB.

The new version will be installed in a new folder Program Files/AppName2/DATA

```
if datafolder exists in program files/appName/DATA

 copy datafolder to Program Files/AppName2/DATA
```

Any suggestions ?
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Source: "{pf}\App\Data\*.*"; DestDir: {code:DataPath}\; Check: DirExists(ExpandConstant('{pf}\App\Data\')); Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs external
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're asking this, as it is similar to your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205803/change-install-location-if-old-installation-used-default-location-program-files) question which I have provided a solution for. Just use the `DirExists` and `FileCopy` functions.

Comment: That I understood, what I did not understand was how could I use this. Did I need to create a procedure, was it possible to use conditions in the Files section of the script? I found the BeforeInstall suport function that I think will allow me to check if the old dir exist and copy it, and then for the new files use the onlyifdoesntexist parameter. I assume this should work

Comment: I suggest you read over the Inno Setup documentation under the 'Pascal Scripting' section.